# File compression - how to implement in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, compression, xattr

I would like to be able to compress certain files (that I need to keep, but use rarely) on disk.  I noticed that `chattr +c` flags a file for compression, but it doesn't seem to actually compress files.

What is the simplest way to implement file compression on a per-file or per-directory basis?

Comment: Write a kernel module that does so.

Comment: Compress them manually?

Comment: Transparent file system compression

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ext2 and family (including ext4) reserve an attribute for compression but don't implement it. This feature was originally put off because there were more urgent things to do, and then it became obsolescent as the size of storage media increased a lot faster than the size of data that isn't already compressed. Most large files today (videos, music, even word processor documents) are already compressed.

Compression can still make sense for medium-sized files. Performance-wise, it's a trade-off: it costs more CPU time but less I/O time.

[Zfs](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/filesystems-zfs.html#idp80854576) includes everything but the kitchen sink, and in particular it does support compression. So does Linux's [btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression).

Comment: Btrfs allows to enable compression on per-file basis. Possibly so ZFS.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a container file that contains a filesystem providing compression (like ZFS). It's not very flexible but pretty simple and probably set up within a few minutes.

Just google for LUKS and container to find how to work with container files. Replacing the LUKS stuff with your favourite filesystem should be rather simple.

Comment: LUKS is only about encryption (not compression) and of block devices (not files). And separate filesystem, even in a file container, is not flexible enough.